# Aspectjrt-1.6.10.jar expected 1.8.10 found 1.6.10

Tags: java, maven, plugins

During maven build I get a warning with aspectJ:

```
[WARNING] bad version number found in C:\development\mavenRepository\org\aspectj\aspectjrt\1.6.10\aspectjrt-1.6.10.jar expected 1.8.10 found 1.6.10
```

This is the pom i'm using:

pom.xml

```xml
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        ...
        <properties>
            <project.build.compiler.source>1.8</project.build.compiler.source>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        </properties>
        <plugins>
            ...
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.1</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                        <version>1.8.10</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${project.build.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${project.build.compiler.source}</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                    <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            ...
        </plugins>
        ...
    </project>
```

What can I do to remove this warning? I have nowhere in my pom the definition that it should use 1.6.10.

It looks like java 8 compiles without problem with that version, but why does it keep downloading and using it?

Even if I declare the dependency below, it still shows the warning and still downloads older version 1.6.10.

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.10</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: one of your dependencies might have a dependency on that older version. have you checked the dependency tree?

Comment: @Stultuske thanks, i didn't think about checking that, i did a search in the results and found one dependency (internal project) that uses exactly that version

Comment: yup. it sure can be a hassle from time to time. glad I could help